# Gallery display horizontally with images with the same size

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I'm working on HTML and CSS and I'm having a hard time aligning the images horizontally instead of vertically.

I tried displaying them inline-block and inline none of them works. And I also want my images to have the same sizes.

Here's my html code:

```css
#gallery {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: inline;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee"><img src="images/gallery1.png"></a>
  <a href="images/gallery2.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="Ian and Vee"><img src="images/gallery2.png"></a>
  <a href="images/gallery3.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="Ian and Vee"><img src="images/gallery3.png"></a>
  <a href="images/gallery4.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="Ian and Vee"><img src="images/gallery4.png"></a>
  <a href="images/gallery5.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="Ian and Vee"><img src="images/gallery5.png"></a>
  <a href="images/gallery6.png" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="Ian and Vee"><img src="images/gallery6.png"></a>
  <script src="lightbox2-master/dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean you want to show all the images vertically...?

Comment: @RameshS i want to show all images horizontally

Comment: @mplungjan nothing lol sorry forgot to delete that

Comment: Please add the relevant code from the lightbox. You can use a CDN

Comment: @JADELAINEFLORES: you got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee">
    <img src="images/gallery1.png" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee">
    <img src="images/gallery1.png" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee">
    <img src="images/gallery1.png" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee">
    <img src="images/gallery1.png" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee">
    <img src="images/gallery1.png" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/gallery1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Ian and Vee">
    <img src="images/gallery1.png" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer. Add a float to your image.

```
#gallery {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: inline;
}

#gallery img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```